# Creating list inside list based on value of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to create a lists inside list. Both of these lists have number of elements that they'll take inside them pre-defined.
For example.

```
num_of_class=5
num_of_subjects=[5,6,4,2,3] #the length of this list is dependent on the value of num_of_class.


outside_list=[] #I want this list to have 5 lists depending on value of num_of_class also
```

Now I want 5(value depending on num_of_class) lists inside outside lists which will take the number of elements inside it based on value of elements in the lists num_of_subjects.

Output example

```
outside_list=[[a,a,a,a,a],[b,b,b,b,b,b],[c,c,c,c],[d,d],[e,e,e]]
```

Comment: what goes inside the inner lists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga strings. Which will be taken as an input by user.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a place where you dump off your work for others to do. There is no actual question here, just a “do this”.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Apparently, I've tried a lot of things and none of them really worked out. If I'd paste my code with the question, it'd serve nothing but make the question difficult to read and understand. No one asks before trying out things.

Comment: @UdaySinghKhalsa _No one asks before trying out things._ Oh boy, I really wish that were always the case... D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```
num_of_class=5
num_of_subjects=[5,6,4,2,3] #the length of this list is dependent on the value of num_of_class.

outside_list=[] #I want this # list to have 5 lists depending on value of num_of_class also
for n in num_of_subjects:
    inp = input('what is the input?')
    outside_list.append([inp for i in range(n)])
```

If you wanted possibly different elements within the inner lists, you could add another inner loop inside the `for n in num_of_subjects` loop like so:

```
num_of_class=5
num_of_subjects=[5,6,4,2,3] #the length of this list is dependent on the value of num_of_class.
outside_list=[] #I want this # list to have 5 lists depending on value of num_of_class also
for n in num_of_subjects:
    inside_list = []
    for j in range(n): 
        inp = input('what is the subject')
        inside_list.append(inp)
    outside_list.append(inside_list)
```

which gets output like:

```
Out[31]: 
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
 ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
 ['p', 'q'],
 ['r', 's', 't']]
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the given example, however I wanted different elements for which I've used to way in the code given below but I'm not able to figure out the way to append the inputs with outer_list to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_of_subjects = [1,2,3,4]
outer_list = []

for classnum, outside in enumerate(lensub, 1):
    for inside in range(outside):
        subjinput = input("Enter subjects for class %d" % classnum)
        outer_list.append([subjinput for n in range(outside)])
```

This takes number of inputs depending on the element value present in the num_of_subjects and after this I'm completely lost with the code.

Comment: you are nearly there! you can just do `outer_list.append(subjinput)`, you don't need the  list comprehension like I used (`[subjinput for n in range(outside)]` - that was only to make a length-N list of identical elements.

Comment: @jeremy_rutmanI tried that. that just creates list for every string inside the outer_list.

Comment: I edited my answer to do this explicitly